# How to secure SSl certificates on a server

Tags: ssl-certificate

Where do you usually store SSL certificates on your server ?

- who are the user and group owners of the certificates folder
- what are the folder permissions

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to store them in `/etc/pkti/tls/certs` (it's a CentOS box); the directory is 755 root:root, and the certificates themselves are 644 root:root.  The **keyfiles** are 600 root:root; that has to be considered enough protection, since if users can read a single file that's 600 root:root the system is compromised.

But I'd like to add a reminder that certificates are **not** secrets; they're given willy-nilly to everyone who connects to your SSL service ports, as they should be.  They should be protected against users **writing** to them, but not from reading.